# Set list of elements in object to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Waypoint` object and want to set several of it's elements to `nil`:

```
waypoint.cep = nil
waypoint.street = nil
waypoint.number = nil
waypoint.district = nil
waypoint.city = nil
waypoint.state = nil
```

There are other elements in the object that I do not want to reset. But still I am sure that there is a prettier way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
%w[ cep street number district city state ].each do |attr|
  waypoint.send("#{attr}=", nil)
end
```